# "You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, dalli

I've been having some caching problems with a footer that is shared across multiple sites, and I'm wondering what might be up. Here's the error message and the backtrace:

```
 Cache read: remote_footer_information ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
 Cache generate: remote_footer_information ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
 Cache write: remote_footer_information ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
 Marshalling error for key 'remote_footer_information': no _dump_data is defined for class Proc
 You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.

 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/server.rb:397:in `dump'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/server.rb:397:in `serialize'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/server.rb:269:in `set'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/server.rb:60:in `request'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/options.rb:18:in `block in request'
    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/options.rb:17:in `request'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:348:in `perform'
    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dalli-2.6.4/lib/dalli/client.rb:199:in `set'
    (eval):7:in `block in set_with_newrelic_trace'
    ...
```

Here's the place where the cache retrieval is being defined:

```
require 'httparty'

module Myclassname
  class Footer
    include HTTParty
    format :json
    attr_accessor :response

    def initialize
      @response = Rails.cache.fetch("remote_footer_information", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
        begin
          self.class.get("http://www.myappname.net/pages/my_footer.json")
        rescue
          false
        end
      end
    end

    def valid?
      unless @response == false || @response.blank?
        return @response['footer'] != nil
      end

      false
    end

    def footer
      unless @response == false || @response.blank?
        return @response['footer']
      end

      nil
    end

  end
end
```

And here's the place in the view where this is being called.

```
<%= yield :footer_legend %>

<div class="clearer"></div>
<div class="divider">
</div>

<% response = Myclassname::Footer.new %>
<% if response && response.valid? %>
    <%= response.footer.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using fragment cache in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the `Httparty::Response` object returned by `Httparty.get` is not serializable, which is required to be cached. Try just caching the part of the response that you need, e.g.

```
response = self.class.get("http://www.myappname.net/pages/my_footer.json")
response['footer'] if response
```

The issue is described [here](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/143).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Turning the HTTParty response into a hash worked for me.

```
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
  HTTParty.get(url).to_hash
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As of httparty version [0.16.3](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/Changelog.md#0163). The HTTParty::Response object is cacheable.

E.g. you can now cache the response object in your cache store out of the box:

```
response = HTTParty.get(...)

store.set(key, Marshal.dump(response))
```